# JSF Buttons in forms sometimes don't perform action

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have problem with organizing forms. When I make one form some buttons (or any other components making ajax calls) don't perform action but they do perform update. When I split the form into two new ones the buttons start working.

In this case buttons and autocomplete don't work.

```
<h:form styleClass="question-#{cc.attrs.question.id}">
    ...

    <p:commandButton value="add answer" update="@form" action="#{questionEditorBean.addAnswer}" />
    <p:commandButton value="save" update="@(.question-#{cc.attrs.question.id})" action="#{cc.attrs.onSave}" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onCancel}" />
    <p:commandButton value="cancel" onclick="#{cc.attrs.onCancel}" />

    <p:autoComplete value="#{questionEditorBean.newTag}" id="tagSelect" completeMethod="#{tagBean.completeTag}" dropdown="true"  
                var="t" itemLabel="#{t.name}" itemValue="#{t}" converter="#{tagConverter}" forceSelection="true">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" action="#{action}" update="@form"/>
</p:autoComplete>
</h:form>
```

When I split the form everything works.

```
<h:form styleClass="question-#{cc.attrs.question.id}">
    ...

    <p:commandButton value="add answer" update="@form" action="#{questionEditorBean.addAnswer}" />
    <p:commandButton value="save" update="@(.question-#{cc.attrs.question.id})" action="#{cc.attrs.onSave}" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onCancel}" />
    <p:commandButton value="cancel" onclick="#{cc.attrs.onCancel}" />

</h:form>
<h:form>

    <p:autoComplete value="#{questionEditorBean.newTag}" id="tagSelect" completeMethod="#{tagBean.completeTag}" dropdown="true"  
                var="t" itemLabel="#{t.name}" itemValue="#{t}" converter="#{tagConverter}" forceSelection="true">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" action="#{action}" update="@form"/>
</p:autoComplete>
</h:form>
```

I don't have nested forms. I am running to this problem all the time. I don't understand this behaviour and I don't want to split buttons and components into more forms when they should be conceptually together. Is there a solution?

Comment: Is `cc.attrs.onCancel` a method in your bean or some text that represents a client side js function ?

Comment: It is JavaScript. Closing of dialog.

Comment: whats action of yours doesn't work in single form?

Comment: In the second example works everything. In the first, buttons don't invoke action on the server but they invoke update and oncomplete. It is very strange because the only difference is separation into two forms.

Comment: In the second example works everything. In the first, buttons don't invoke action on the server but they invoke update and oncomplete. It is very strange because the only difference is separation into two forms. Also when I remove the autocomplete in the first case, the buttons start working. I am suffering from this problem on many places not only with buttons and autocomplete but also with buttons only.

Comment: and what is that action="#{action}" ? shouldn't it be `action="#{someBean.someAction}"` ?

Comment: Action is a variable. It is someBean.someAction. But if it wasn't correct it would fail in the second example too. Moreover this would not influence the buttons. It has to be something with the forms. I am new to JSF, I have to be missing something. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the form an `id` and set `prependId="false"`, as in this example:

```
<h:form id="ccForm" prependId="false">
```

Then you add the form id to all `update` targets.

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" action="#{action}" update="ccForm:tagSelect" />
```

This way you make explicit what are the `update` targets inside your composite component.

Also I noticed that you're trying to use `styleClass` as an `id` in your form, and trying to update it. Following this way I suggested, make its `update` property look like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="save" update="ccForm:question-#{cc.attrs.question.id}" action="#{cc.attrs.onSave}" oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onCancel}" />
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I used styleClass because I wanted all components with this class on page to be updated. I would use name attribute but JSF won't let me. So is it normal behaviour that the action is not invoked on server without any warning but elements in update are updated? I was hoping for some solution to make it work with one form.